# Putting the image behind the background

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a simple html, but I'm not sure if what I want to do (the way I want to do it) is possible..

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

.container has some sort of gradient background, in this case a common black bottom for text

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.7));
```

this is simulated in http://jsfiddle.net/9WQL6/

I want the dark bottom to be in front of the picture, not behind it.

I can't use a `background-image` for the image because the css is precompiled.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to go is with a pseudo-element (IE8+)

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9WQL6/5/)**

**CSS**

```
.container{
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.container img{
    max-width: 200px;
}

.container:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:" ";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(0.65, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)), color-stop(1, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.5)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.7));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.7));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.7));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.7));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 65%, rgba(47, 39, 39, 0.7));
}
```

Comment: Nice.. +1 for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Give the image negative `z-index`:

```
.container > img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Will still take the space in the block

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes it will. What's the problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a diffrent div in your container and apply the gradient on that div. The image will be in `.container`.
You put the containerdiv on position relative and the gradientdiv on absolute and make it the same width and height as the containerdiv.

In my example I gave the gradientdiv the class `gradient`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gradient">
    </div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/800px-Smiley.svg.png" />
</div>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/9WQL6/9/